# Throwing an exception in destructor method

Tags: php, exception, destructor

I cannot find a reliable source to ensure that I am able to throw an exception inside `__destruct()`.

This is what php documentation says

> Attempting to throw an exception from a destructor (called in the time of script termination) causes a fatal error.

But when I test it

```
class A 
{
    public function __destruct()
    {
       throw new \Exception();
    }
}

try {
    $a = new A();

} catch(\Exception $x) {
    var_dump($x);
}
```

it seems that this is not true. I throw and catch exceptions normally. So, why has the doc got this line?

edited after Mark Baker's answer:

it actually works, the exception can be thrown and caught from destructor. I am still uncertain why the documentation lies then.

Comment: Destructor isn't being called at all in your example code; try [unsetting `$a`](https://3v4l.org/qYe67) and it will throw an exception

Comment: Otherwise, an exception is thrown when the script terminates; but that is outside of your try/catch

Comment: 'called in the time of script termination' is the hint.

Comment: @MarkBaker how could I miss that... You're absolutely right. So, the exception thrown in destructor cannot be caught

Comment: @MarkBaker can you post it as an answer so that I will be able to accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The destructor isn't being called anywhere in your script, so your try/catch block won't catch anything. If you `unset($x)` inside the try/catch block, then an exception will be thrown, and duly caught.

```
class A {
    public function __destruct() {
       throw new \Exception();
    }
}

try {
    $a = new A();
    unset($a);
} catch(\Exception $x) {
    var_dump($x);
}
```

Otherwise, PHP throws an exception when the script terminates, but that is outside of your try/catch block

**EDIT**

The exception thrown on script termination if your object hasn't been manually destroyed can't be caught because you can't wrap try/catch around the PHP's internal termination handling that destroys the object; and this is what results in a fatal error

> Fatal Error: Uncaught Exception

So this is what the documentation is warning you about

Comment: I tested it, it works. Thank you. But why the doc lies then?

Comment: If you execute the code that I posted, then the exception that's thrown when `$a` is unset is caught, and var dumped [Demo](https://3v4l.org/0jlBa)

Comment: you're right, I edited my comment but not fast enough, sorry.

Comment: The documentation doesn't lie.... it simply identifies that the exception thrown when the object is destroyed on script termination cannot be caught, and thus results in a `Fatal Error: Uncaught Exception` - [Demo](https://3v4l.org/YDv1D)

Comment: Mark Bakes, to add to what you are saying, seems like not even set_exception_handler can "catch" these exceptions thrown at script termination, because I had this issue, and here I found the explanation, I think.